# NLTK: Auto suggestion for query completion using grammar

Tags: python, autocomplete, nlp, nltk, context-free-grammar

I want to implement [Auto-Suggestion for question completion](http://iswc2015.semanticweb.org/sites/iswc2015.semanticweb.org/files/93670017.pdf) (Refer Section 3.2) for my FCFG using nltk APIs.

E.g.
Consider the following CFG grammar:

```
S -> NP VP
NP -> Det NN | PropN
VP -> V NP | V
V -> 'eats' | 'sleeps' | 'ate'
Det -> 'a' | 'an' | 'the'
NN -> 'police' | 'horse' | 'apple' | 'potato'
PropN -> 'Robin'
```

After each word of input, what I want is a module which suggests me all possible lexicons which can follow my current input.

E.g. If I type *Robin*, my grammar should parse this and my module should suggest the left-most leaf from the sub-tree that just follows *Robin* parent's production i.e. `NP -> PropN`. Since in this case nothing follows `PropN`, I want it to search for the parent of `PropN` i.e. `S -> NP VP`. Since `VP` follows `NP`, my module should should print `VP`'s left-most leaf(for every `VP` production, in this case only `V`) i.e.: *eats, sleeps, ate*.

I'm using nltk and my grammar is FCFG. Any help is appreciated.